# Hiding/Unhiding all paragraphs with a certain markup

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible, using HTML and JavaScript (and CSS), to do have a link I can click on that will toggle the visibility of all DOM elements with a special CLASS attached? It doesn't necessarily need to be a CLASS. Another option (if possible) is a new tag, f.ex. `<P2>` that works like `<P>` (inheritance?) that I can use on the paragraphs that need to be toggleable. The primary requirement is that a single click will toggle *all* the paragraphs (or `<DIV>`s, or whatever) at the click.

I.e..

`<P CLASS="Hideable">This text can be toggled visible/hidden</P>`

and then

`<A onClick="<some javascript>">Hide/Unhide</A>`

The "`<some javascript>`" part should then toggle the visibility of all `<P>`s with the class "Hideable".

Note: I'm a novice in HTML/JavaScript/CSS, so please don't assume I know what you are talking about :-)

Comment: Yes, this is a very basic and common manipulation.  You can either toggle the style of the elements directly or you can toggle adding and removing an additional class that is defined so the elements do not appear.  StackOverflow is not friendly to these broad questions, so you might get less down votes to try a search first.

Comment: *Note: I'm a novice in HTML/JavaScript/CSS, so please don't assume I know what you are talking about :-)* <-- SO isn't a tutorial site. You should begin to learn HTML, CSS, and JavaScript if you need to write code for web pages. We are also not a code writing service.

Comment: i agree @ScottMarcus i removed my answer and downvoted the question. 
I just tried showing that it very simple without using any of the best practises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up an event listener for the click
`const toggler = document.querySelector('.hide-items'); toggler.addEventListener('click', function(event) {`

Then prevent that link:
`event.preventDefault();`

Then toggle the `hidden` class on all elements with that `hideable` class.

```js
const toggler = document.querySelector('.hide-items');
toggler.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const matches = document.querySelectorAll('.hideable');
  matches.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.hideable {
  border: solid 1px #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<p class="hideable">This text can be toggled visible/hidden</p>
<p class="hideable">This text can be toggled visible/hidden</p>
<p class="hideable">This text can be toggled visible/hidden</p>
<p>This text can NOT be toggled visible/hidden</p>
<p class="hideable">This text can be toggled visible/hidden</p>
<p class="hideable">This text can be toggled visible/hidden</p>
<p class="hideable">This text can be toggled visible/hidden</p>

and then

<a class="hide-items" href="#">Hide/Unhide</a>
```

Comment: Additionally, your answer relies on using a hyperlink as a JavaScript hook, which is not a good thing. Hyperlinks are for navigation and to use them otherwise will cause problems for those using screen readers.